# how to use adminfaces spring boot master?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, adminfaces

I am new to spring boot, I am trying to use the master dashboard to be admin faces spring boot master.
I download the project from GitHub, https://github.com/miltonbo/adminfaces-spring-boot
when I run the project, I got this eror:"APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field adminSession in com.github.adminfaces.template.session.AdminFilter required a bean of type 'com.github.adminfaces.template.session.AdminSession' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value="loginMB")

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
- User-defined bean
- User-defined bean

Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'com.github.adminfaces.template.session.AdminSession' in your configuration."
I just download it and run it on eclipse.
how do I correct it?
plus there are admin.properties under resource but there are no application.properties in this project, should I do the application.properties under resources?
please forward me a link if there is a spring boot admin faces master that works easily?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AdminFaces and SpringBoot integration you need to use JoinFaces, check AdminFaces SpringBoot sample application here: https://github.com/adminfaces/admin-starter-springboot